# cross platform FILTER_PATTERNS in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I have a Doxyfile which works fine under linux. It contains a FILTER_PATTERNS element which looks like this:

```
*.py="python python_packages/utilities/doxygenFilter.py"
```

where python is in the path and python_packages/utilities/doxygenFilter.py is under the working directory (at this stage the doxygenFilter.py just prints "bla")

This works fine in linux (both ubuntu and centos) but when I try to use the same in windows I get errors such as:

```
Reading "somefile"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Is there a way to do this in windows (and better yet make it work in both windows and linux with the same doxyfile)?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions this was not possible, but in the current version this should be possible.
When using the `-d extcmd` option in the older versions you would see something like:

`` Executing popen(`"python python_packages/utilities/doxygenFilter.py" "<your file>"`) ``

In the version from 1.8.12 you will get:

`` Executing popen(`python python_packages/utilities/doxygenFilter.py "<your file>"`) ``

and the process should run.